# dashboard in jasperserver 4.5

Tags: jasperserver

I want to do a lot of things that I found them in the net and jasperreport can do it,
but in my screen, I don't found the menu to create dashboards, I don't find also a lot of folders in repository ...

why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This comparison](http://www.jaspersoft.com/editions) of what is in the different product editions should make it clear.